# Unity to return new instance of service

Tags: wpf, unity-container

I have come across a bit of a problem while using Unity and WPF.  The scenario is I have a WPF application which follows the MVVM design pattern.  A have a module called ViewKDI. Within this module I have a service called ViewKDIService, the ViewKDIService service utilises another service called UserService.

Every time I load the module ViewKDI I want Unity to return me a new instance of both the ViewKDIService and the UserService.

I have put the below in the shell bootstrapper:

```
Container.RegisterType<IUserService, UserService>();
```

In the ViewKDI module I have put the following:

```
Container.RegisterType<IViewKDIService, ViewKDIService>();
```

Each time the ViewKDI module loads the ViewKDIService constructor is called.  However the UserService constructor is only called the first time, this means that I am not getting a new instance of UserService.

I require unity to give me a new instance of UserService too so that I can manage this session separately from the rest of the application.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Faisal

Comment: Can you provide more details on when you are resolving each type? Is IUserService a dependency of ViewKDIService?

Comment: I'm not explicitly calling resolve, I've just put the Interfaces in the Constructor of my ViewModel and am letting Unity resolve them.

IUserService is not dependant on IViewKDIService.

Comment: It would be helpful to see which objects IUserService and IViewKDIService are injected into to understand their lifetime. For example are both injected into your ViewModel or just IUserService?

Answer (score 2):

Unity's default behaviour is to create a new instance of each object each time one is requested, so you shouldn't be seeing this behaviour.

From what I can gather from the source code and MSDN documentation ([this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc440947.aspx) is a good read), you can specify a "lifetime manager" object when you register a type to tell Unity how the type should be constructed and cached. Using the TransientLifetimeManager (which essentially does no caching) will cause Unity to re-create the class each time. So try this:

```
Container.RegisterType<IUserService, UserService>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
```

... and see if it creates a new UserService each time.